# Gauss Newton minimization of 2D linear function

Tags: optimization, gauss-sums

Given the input-output relation:

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        y_1 \\
        y_2 
        \end{pmatrix}
=p_1
        \begin{pmatrix}
        p_2 & p_3 \\
        p_4 & p_4
        \end{pmatrix}
*
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 
        \end{pmatrix}
+
        \begin{pmatrix}
        p_5 \\
        p_6 
        \end{pmatrix}
$

with $p_1-p_6$ parameters.I want to minimize the least square error using Gauss-Newton method. Suppose we have 100 measurements.
My question is about calculation and size of residual vector.

$ r_i = output - f(input,parameters) \\
 \begin{pmatrix}
        r_1 \\
        r_2 
        \end{pmatrix}
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
        y_1 \\
        y_2 
        \end{pmatrix}
-
\Bigg( p_1
        \begin{pmatrix}
        p_2 & p_3 \\
        p_4 & p_4
        \end{pmatrix}
*
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 
        \end{pmatrix}
+
        \begin{pmatrix}
        p_5 \\
        p_6 
        \end{pmatrix}\Bigg)
$

In order to calculate minimised-error parameters, we have:

$
 p_{i+1}=p_i+\Delta
\\\Delta=(J_f^TJ^T)^{-1}J_f^Tr_i
$

the size of each is as follows:

$
input vector :100*2\\
output vector :100*2\\
r:\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad100*2\\
J_f : \quad\quad\quad\quad100*6\\
p_i:\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad6*1 (six \quad parameters)
$

As you can see, the size of $\Delta$ would be 6x2 that seems not consistent with $p_{i+1}$

Now is my residual vector calculation process right? if yes how can I compute parameter's vector? And if not what is the correct answer?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Let me correct your Gauss-Newton step:

$$\Delta=-\left(J_{f}^{T}J_{f}\right)^{-1}J_{f}^{T}r$$

In terms of matrix sizes:

$$\left([100\times 6]^{T}[100\times 6]\right)^{-1}[100\times 6]^{T}[100\times 1]=\\ \left([6\times100][100\times 6]\right)^{-1}[6\times 100][100\times 1]=\\ ([6\times6])^{-1}[6\times 1]=\\ [6\times 6][6\times 1]=\\ [6\times 1]$$

Hence the $\Delta$ is a vector with 6 rows which is of the same size as $p_{i}$ and you can compute $p_{i+1}=p_{i}+\Delta$.

You can [take a look here](http://www.imagingshop.com/articles/least-squares#nonlinear-gn) for derivation of the Gauss-Newton step.

Answer (score 0):

You could vectorize the multicolumn vectors, like residuals (i.e. $r \to 100 \times 2$ becomes $200 \times 1$). Same goes for Jacobian (in your case $J_f$ should have size $2N\times 6$), and all matrix multiplications should work well.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This does not appear to provide a complete answer to the question, and may be better left as a comment below their post. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).